# URL rewriting between different pools with different authentication in IIS

Tags: iis, load-balancing, redirect, iis-7.5, rewrite

I have an IIS application and three sub-applications as follows:

```
CMT (Windows and Anonymously authenticated)
- CI
- EM
- Website (Windows authenticated)
```

CI and EM are helper web services and Website is -obviously- the website. Now, if the application is hosted under cmt.mycompany.com, then the user can access the website as follows:

cmt.mycompany.com/website/mypage

I want to write a URL Rewrite rule so that our users don't have to write 'website' after the DNS, and can simply open `cmt.mycompany.com` or `cmt.mycompany.com/mypage` to open the main page or mypage, respectively.

```
<rule name="WebsiteMapping" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(?!\b(?:ci|em|website)\b).*$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/website/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

What this rule does is simply rewrite any URL that doesn't start with `ci`, `em`, or `website` to have `website` added after the DNS.

I am having two problems that I don't seem to be able to solve:

1. For some reason, URL Rewrite doesn't seem to work with authentication so whenever I hit `cmt.mycompany.com`, I get a dialog ask me to authenticate myself and it doesn't work even if I enter my credentials. Since the main application (CMT) and the website are hosted under different app pools, we needed to install IIS ARR, but that didn't help.
2. I tried to change the rule to 'redirect' and it did work, but there is another problem. So I have a load balancer connected to 4 individual boxes. The load balancer is hosted under port 80, but the individual boxes are hosted under port 9991. When I hit the individual boxes, the URL redirect works successfully, but when I hit the load balancer dns, the port 9991 (of the individual box) gets appended to the load balancer dns!! For example, if I hit `cmt.mycompany.com/mypage`, I get redirected to `cmt.mycompany.com:9991/website/mypage` which is obviously invalid since the load balancer is hosted on port number 80 not 9991.

Any idea to help my solve these problems?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah the rewrite would keep the client thinking they were looking at the same URL. Can you just make a redirect page on the root of the site on the load balancers?  i.e. person tries to hit cmt.mycompany.com/ it brings up the default page that just redirects to cmt.mycompany.com/website.  Set all of the custom error pages on just the root level to go to the default page.

Comment: Also, when you changed it to redirect did you only change the action to redirect, or did more of the configuration change? I'm thinking maybe you added an outbound rule to add the 9991 by accident. Generally you don't need to make a rule change the outbound traffic, it does it on it's own.

Comment: I can make a redirect page, but that will only redirect the home page, i.e. I won't be able to redirect `cmt.mycompany.com/mypage` to `cmt.mycompany.com/website/mypage` is it will not hit the home page.

Comment: No, I just changed "rewrite" to "redirect".

Comment: You can do that, actually.  Make a .net page and use this code in the main method: Response.Redirect("http://" + Request.Url.ServerName +  "/WebSite" + Request.Url.PathAndQuery);

Comment: Actually, rewrite would be the way to go in this situation, I just looked at a similar setup that we have. Are you using NTML or Windows Integrated login? If NTLM, it's not supported with ARR yet: http://forums.iis.net/t/1150821.aspx. If windows, you might want to look into making sure Kerberos is configured properly. Here's a reference for SharePoint http://blogs.msdn.com/b/echarran/archive/2010/02/11/howto-configure-sharepoint-2010-for-kerberos.aspx that should be the same approach you'll have to take for standard apps also.

Comment: Thanks very much Snowburnt. Yeah, I did read somewhere similar information, but honestly, I got a bit confused, I am not IIS guy :)

Comment: I will check with the team responsible about this in the company and be back to you.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possibilities, NTLM is not supported with URL rewrite + ARR. For Windows integrated authentication you may have to configure Kerberos to get it working properly.

Here's a page describing the general steps for sharepoint, but it's applicable elsewhere: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/echarran/archive/2010/02/11/howto-configure-sharepoint-2010-for-kerberos.aspx

From a deep dive in the article, you have to create Service Principal Names for the web applications and delegate control to the web application identity. To create the SPN, use a command like this: (HTTP applies for both HTTP and HTTPS)

```
setspn -s HTTP/[domain name of application] [domain name]\[server name hosting application]
```

Set an SPN for each domain you will need to authenticate to and for each server the applications are hosted on (if you have a web farm).  Next, open up active directory and set the view to advanced mode.  Open up the computer object for one of the web servers.  Go to the delegation tab.  Change the radio button to "Trust this user for delegation to specified services only", make sure the next radio button is "Use any authentication protocol".  Click Add. search for the application pool identities (if it's Network Service, you don't have to worry about this part).  click ok.  On add services, select all of them that this application pool identity is in charge of and click okay.

---

Alternatively, it may be easier to just make a default page on the root that will redirect traffic to the proper location, something like this:

```
Response.Redirect("http://" + Request.Url.ServerName + "/WebSite" + Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
```

Set up the custom errors on the default site to use this page.  I'll do some testing, but you may have to make another page for errors that uses the referral URI's PathAndQuery to send it to the right place.